# Loading PHP file on click

Tags: javascript, php, database

The task at hand I cannot solve is loading a PHP file into a JavaScript file upon clicking a button. 
I do not want the PHP or the result to be shown on the page. I just want to have access to the result string generated by the PHP file.

I am aware of JS being clientside and PHP serverside, but loading all PHP files I need in the beginning, results in a break down.

The snippets below show how I am doing right now.
Unfortunately, this does not work to well and so far there is no button directly involved either of course. (see: [MIME type error when loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234559/mime-type-error-when-loading-data) )

**db2js.php** (pulling data from a database and converting it into a JSON-like string)

```
<?php    
    CONNECTING TO DATABASE
    QUERY
    $result=RESULT OF QUERY LOOKING LIKE JSON
    echo 'db_output='.$result;    
?>
```

**index.html** (the file where the data is needed)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="db2js.php"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            var JSON_db_output = JSON.parse(db_output);
            document.write(dbausgabe);
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alternate solutions very welcome!

Comment: aww to bad you're not using jquery - could be done with `.load()` haha :(

Comment: Not sure if this still works but you might be able to cheat the mime-type by changing the src to `db2js.php?foo=.js`. Alternatively you should use an asynchronous request in your JS to get the contents of db2js.php. If all you want is a json structure that should be easy.

Comment: Did you set the correct header in your PHP file, like: `header("Content-Type: application/javascript");`?

Comment: I didn't know that there is such thing as a content-type in the header in PHP. Still new to PHP. I'll see if this fixes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement ***AJAX is best solution***. You can get idea by following code snippet :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {


                $( "#b1" ).on( "click", function() {

            console.log('button click');
                    disen(this);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "your_php_page.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { key1 : "your_value1", key2 : "your_value2" },
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#info').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $('#info').html(textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            disen("#b1");
                        },
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<span id="info"></span><br>

<input type="button" id="b1" value="test">

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this code snippet help you to resolve your issue.
Anything need more about it please let me know.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot! 
I am using a div instead of a span element and just made it invisible with `style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px;"`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: It's fine, I also said that alternate solutions would be welcome even though JavaScript only would have been more comfortable.

Comment: @Katstrophenmagnet ah no worries then :) will remove my other comments haha - I've been stung heavily when offering a jquery solution for a js-tagged question - didn't want my comrades to experience the same haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      <?php    
        CONNECTING TO DATABASE
        QUERY
        $result=RESULT OF QUERY LOOKING LIKE JSON
        echo 'var db_output='.$result;    
      ?>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      var JSON_db_output = JSON.parse(db_output);
      document.write(dbausgabe);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this, it would not change anything except for the fact, that I got around 20k lines of data printed in front of the navigation of the website. What are your thoughts behind this solution?

Comment: Well! I tried you to help without bringing much change in your code. I think you got your solution and now you know why the 20k lines of data printed in front of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use ajax

on html code add your button with id or class

```
<input type ="button" id="myphploader">

<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

assuming you have you php file as `"file1.php"`, use this javascript function

```
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery_002.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

              $("#myphploader").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file1.php", // your php file
    data: { variable1: variable1}, // incase you want to pass an value to  php file
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#div1").html(html).show();




  }
  });


  });

 });
    </script>
```

you can get the result from the "div1" using

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know jQuery and can use Ajax try it like this

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "db2js.php",
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        document.write(response);
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

db2js.php

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    $json = json_encode($arr);
    echo $json;
    exit();
?>
```